# Lucene query syntax in Kibana

Tags: lucene, kibana

Im struggling to search for a simple phrase using Lucene syntax in Kibana.

We have logs that look like the following lines:

*API :: GetStatus :: MP181210.1524.O47211 :: Not found.

API :: GetStatus :: MP181210.1144.V12345 :: Found - some random stuff here.*

I want to find all the lines that have **"Found - "** in them, so I figured (since hyphen is a reserved symbol) that I should search for:

*"API :: GetStatus ::" AND "Found \-"*

However, that for some reason just ignores the trailing hyphen and these are the results I get

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Double blackslash?

Comment: @K.Nicholas I tried that as a last ditch effort (although that would imply an escaped blackslash according to Lucene query syntax documentation!) but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't really your query syntax (hyphens are not reserved characters when quoted in a phrase, by the way, so escaping wouldn't be necessary). Lucene analyzes it's input into tokens, or terms in lucene parlance, which it indexes and makes searchable. The default analyzer (and most analyzers, really) tries to tokenize it into words. The hyphen will be treated as punctuation, so it is not indexed and is not searchable. In order to search for it, you would need to change your analyzer and reindex.

Comment: Makes 100% sense when I think about it in the context of Kibana :)